# Checking whether a commit hash has already been deployed in git

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have an online app that has been deployed with a specific commit hash (i.e. `git checkout commitHash`).

And given a specific branch, I wanted to check whether another commit hash comes before the deployed commit hash.  What would be the best way to do it?  Is there a git command or shell script where I can provide both hashes and it can tell me?

Context: I'm essentially wanting to check whether a specific commit hash has been deployed or not for a specific environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `git log` with `..` notation.

```
git log <hashA>..<hashB>
```

This will give output if <hashA> is before <hashB> but it will have no output if <hashB> is before <hashA>. (This is assuming, as in your case, that the revisions are on the same branch).

To be more formal, `<hashA>..<hashB>` includes commits that are reachable (via parent references) from <hashB> but excludes those that are reachable from <hashA>. The [gitrevisions man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) has more information.